# drag and drop over 2 components with a filled div

Tags: angular

I have a project with a parent and child. Within the child is a div container with a lot of objects on it. I added an id to the div object and need to build a drop zone in the parent and catch the id there in an array and delete objects in the child with the same id. Thanks in advance.

I didn´t get it working, the last try way the usage of ngxDragDrop. There was the problem that this isn´t working within firefox at all.

The Drag mode is enabled by:

draggable="true"

There is actually no result because the dropzone is missing, through a lot of  tries.

Comment: Why not go with native drag and drop code instead of using a library? See https://medium.com/@svsh227/implement-drag-and-drop-in-angular-2-4-5-6-f27f210a0245. You can set the data using`dataTransfer` property.

Comment: Thank you, i will try it as fast as possible.